# Detecting clicks versus drags on an html 5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mouseevent

I am trying to write a simple map with the HTML 5 canvas. Dragging the mouse moves the map, and clicking selects the closest waypoint. However, there is a problem. When I drag the mouse, I still get the *click* event when I release it. I would like to get that only if there was no movement while clicking.

I tried to check for a no movement event in the *mousemove* event handler, but with no success:

```
function onMove(e) {
    if(e.movementX == 0 && e.movementY == 0) {
        console.log("a"); //never happens...
    }
}
```

My question is: is there an easy way to do it, or should I check if the press and release event were at the same place?

Here is my code:

```
function onMove(e) {
    console.log("moving");
}

function onClick(e) {
    console.log("clicked");
}

function init() {
    c = document.getElementById("MapCanvas");
    ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    c.addEventListener("click", onClick, true);
    c.addEventListener("mousemove", onMove, true);
}
```

Comment: post your event handlers and sample html. Read [mcve]

Comment: Try the mousedown event for selection instead of click.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Here is one way to solve this:**

As we need to know two states we need two flags (some prefer objects - it's up to you):

```
var isDown = false;    // mouse button is held down
var isMoving = false;  // we're moving (dragging)
```

Then we need to find a way to distinguish between a drag and a click. A typical approach is to use a radius (length) between first click point to the current point: if outside we consider it to be a drag operation.

So -

```
var radius = 9 * 9     // radius in pixels, 9 squared
var firstPos;          // keep track of first position
```

(We're squaring the 9 so we don't have to calculate square-root for every mouse move event later).

Then we can define our callback handlers to consider these things:

```
canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
  firstPos = getXY(e); // record click position (see getXY function in demo)
  isDown = true;       // record mouse state
  isMoving = false;    // reset move state
};
```

The next handlers can be set on `window` object instead of the canvas element itself. This allows us to move outside the canvas element while the mouse button is held. We need to use `addEventListener()` here so we allow other code to subscribe as well:

```
window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  if (!isDown) return; // we will only act if mouse button is down
  var pos = getXY(e);  // get current mouse position

  // calculate distance from click point to current point
  var dx = firstPos.x - pos.x,
      dy = firstPos.y - pos.y,
      dist = dx * dx + dy * dy;        // skip square-root (see above)

  if (dist >= radius) isMoving = true; // 10-4 we're on the move

  if (isMoving) {
    // handle move operation here
  }
});
```

And finally we detect for click as well as updating mouse state, also this on the `window` object:

```
window.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
  if (!isDown) return;   // no need for us in this case
  isDown = false;        // record mouse state

  if (!isMoving) {
    // it was a click, handle click operation here
  }
});
```

Then final problem is then to click the way-point. Doing an absolute check (i.e. x === value) will rarely turn out OK as we need to place the mouse button exactly at that point. Allow a range using the width and height of the way point (assuming an object `wp` for the way-point):

```
if (pos.x >= wp.x && pos.x < wp.x + wp.width && 
    pos.y >= wp.y && pos.y < wp.y + wp.height) { ... }
```

## Example

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var wp = {x: 50, y:50, width:12, height:12};  // demo way-point
ctx.font = "20px sans-serif";
ctx.fillText("Click or click+move on this canvas...", 10, 30);
ctx.strokeRect(wp.x, wp.y, wp.width, wp.height);

var isDown = false;        // mouse button is held down
var isMoving = false;      // we're moving (dragging)
var radius = 9 * 9         // radius in pixels, 9 squared
var firstPos;              // keep track of first position

canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  ctx.strokeRect(wp.x, wp.y, wp.width, wp.height);
  
  firstPos = getXY(e);
  isDown = true;           // record mouse state
  isMoving = false;        // reset move state
};

window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  if (!isDown) return;     // we will only act if mouse button is down
  var pos = getXY(e);      // get current mouse position

  // calculate distance from click point to current point
  var dx = firstPos.x - pos.x,
      dy = firstPos.y - pos.y,
      dist = dx * dx + dy * dy;        // skip square-root (see above)

  if (dist >= radius) isMoving = true; // 10-4 we're on the move

  if (isMoving) {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.strokeRect(wp.x, wp.y, wp.width, wp.height);
    ctx.fillText("MOVING", 10, 30);
  }
});

window.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
  if (!isDown) return;     // no need for us in this case
  isDown = false;          // record mouse state

  if (!isMoving) {
    if (firstPos.x >= wp.x && firstPos.x < wp.x + wp.width &&
        firstPos.y >= wp.y && firstPos.y < wp.y + wp.height) {
      ctx.fillText("CLICKED WAYPOINT", 10, 30);
    }
    else {
      ctx.fillText("CLICK", 10, 30);
    }
  }
});

function getXY(e) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {x: e.clientX - rect.left, y: e.clientY - rect.top}
}
```

```css
canvas {background:#ccc}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=620 height=180></canvas>
```

Comment: Good answer and demo -- as usual. :-) Upvote. Since this question is asked fairly often, would you consider adding a preface to your answer about *"Why mouseclicks versus drags are a problem"*? If yes, I'll refer to your Q&A here as "canonical" when the questions arises in the future. Cheers!

Comment: @markE sounds good to me. I'll come back a little later to update.